# How to highlight the current line number in `nlinum-mode`

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am writing a minor mode to highlight the current line number when using `nlinum-mode` (written by @Stefan), and I got everything working *except* **when the cursor is on the first line at the top of the window**.

The code for `nlinum-mode` can be found here:  http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/nlinum.html

Any assistance in figuring out why this doesn't work (i.e., **when the cursor is on the first line at the top of the window**) would be greatly appreciated.

```lisp
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; M-x hl-nlinum-mode

(defvar nlinum-highlight-current-line-number-string nil
  "An overlay string used to highlight the current line number.")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'nlinum-highlight-current-line-number-string)

(defvar nlinum-highlight-p nil
  "Set to non-`nil` when overlay is present, and `nil` when not present.")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'nlinum-highlight-p)

(defface ln-active-face
  '((t (:foreground "black" :background "#eab700" :bold nil :italic nil
      :underline nil :box nil :overline nil)))
  "Face for `ln-active-face`."
  :group 'linum)

(defface ln-inactive-face
  '((t (:foreground "SteelBlue" :background "black" :bold t :italic nil
      :underline nil :box nil :overline nil)))
  "Face for `ln-active-face`."
  :group 'linum)

(defun hl-nlinum-remove-overlay ()
  (when nlinum-highlight-p
    (remove-overlays (point-min) (point-max)
      'before-string nlinum-highlight-current-line-number-string)
    (setq nlinum-highlight-p nil)))

(defun nlinum-highlight-current-line-number ()
  (when nlinum-mode
    (hl-nlinum-remove-overlay)
    (let* (
        (pbol (point-at-bol))
        (line (nlinum--line-number-at-pos))
        (line-mod
          (cond
            ((eq nlinum--width 2)
              (cond
                ((< line 10)
                  (concat " " (format "%s" line)))
                (t (format "%s" line))))
            ((eq nlinum--width 3)
              (cond
                ((< line 10)
                  (concat "  " (format "%s" line)))
                ((and
                    (> line 9)
                    (< line 100))
                  (concat " " (format "%s" line)))
                (t (format "%s" line))))
            ((eq nlinum--width 4)
              (cond
                ((< line 10)
                  (concat "   " (format "%s" line)))
                ((and
                    (> line 9)
                    (< line 100))
                  (concat "  " (format "%s" line)))
                ((and
                    (> line 99)
                    (< line 1000))
                  (concat " " (format "%s" line)))
                (t (format "%s" line))))
            (t (format "%s" line))))
        (str (propertize line-mod 'face 'ln-active-face) )
        (final-line-number (propertize " " 'display `((margin left-margin) ,str))))
      (setq nlinum-highlight-current-line-number-string final-line-number)
      (overlay-put (make-overlay pbol pbol)
        'before-string nlinum-highlight-current-line-number-string)
      (setq nlinum-highlight-p t))))

(define-minor-mode hl-nlinum-mode
"A minor-mode for highlighting the current line number when nlinum-mode is active."
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " HL#"
  :keymap nil
  :global nil
  :group 'linum
  (cond
    (hl-nlinum-mode
      (when (not nlinum-mode)
         (nlinum-mode 1))
      (add-hook 'post-command-hook #'nlinum-highlight-current-line-number nil t))
    (t
      (remove-hook 'post-command-hook #'nlinum-highlight-current-line-number t)
      (remove-overlays (point-min) (point-max)
        'before-string nlinum-highlight-current-line-number-string))))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: Can you share the current line number highlighting code for `nlinum`? Thanks!

Comment: @kaushalmodi -- I ended up using a custom creation that only draws line numbers on the visible portion of a window, and updates with the post-command-hook and the window-scroll- functions hook.  However, I am not using nlinum-mode.  Sorry, I don't have a working solution for nlinum-mode.

Comment: See:  https://github.com/hlissner/emacs-nlinum-hl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably in your call to `(hl-nlinum-remove-overlay)`.  I'm not completely sure I understand the way your code is expected to work, but here's my analysis: the main issue you have is that you want your overlay to *replace* nlinum's, but doing it from `post-command-hook` won't always work, because nlinum adds its overlays via jit-lock which is typically run by redisplay, i.e. *after* post-command-hook.

I think you can fix this problem by calling `jit-lock-fontify-now` on the current line in `nlinum-highlight-current-line-number`.  Whether that will fix your "first line is wrong", I'm not sure, tho.

This said, I think your code shouldn't try to *replace* nlinum's overlay.  Instead it should go and *modify* nlinum's overlay.  I.e.:

- Call `jit-lock-fontify-now`
- Then look for nlinum's overlay on the current line
- If it's a different overlay than the last one (which you stashed in a `hl-nlinum--last-overlay`), then un-modify the last overlay.
- Finally, modify the current line's overlay with something like the code below.

If `ol` is nlinum's current line's overlay, you should be able to modify it with something like:

```
(let* ((spc (overlay-get ol 'before-string))
       (disp (get-text-property 0 'display spc))
       (str (nth 1 disp)))
  (put-text-property 0 (length str) 'face 'foo str))
```

Comment: Thank you -- this will be a work in progress.  I'll report back once I've had some time to digest your suggestions and experiment a bit.  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible we need to add something like `str` after `'foo`, and perhaps change `(1- (length str))` to `(length str)`?  Otherwise, I get an `(args-out-of-range 0 1)` message.  The following seems to work a little better:  `(let* ((ov (catch 'found (dolist (ol (overlays-at (point))) (and (overlay-get ol 'before-string) (throw 'found ol))))) (spc (overlay-get ov 'before-string)) (disp (get-text-property 0 'display spc)) (str (nth 1 disp))) (put-text-property 0 (length str) 'face 'bold str))`

Comment: Very possibly.  This was pure unadulterated 100%-guaranteed untested code.

Comment: I edited my code based on your comments.  As for your code, note that checking `before-string` is not a good idea.  Better check the `nlinum` property instead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and sample code to get me started -- greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would you like to modify your answer to include the new feature mentioned by @Kaushal Modi in the alternative answer `(setq nlinum-highlight-current-line t)` so that we can keep your check-mark where it is?

Answer (score 5):

You can enable highlighting the current line number in version 1.7 of [`nlinum`](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/nlinum-1.7.el) package by setting this in your config:

```el
(setq nlinum-highlight-current-line t)
```

Comment: Since this is now the correct answer, should I change the check-mark or should we try to convince the author/maintainer of `nlinum` to update his previous answer with this new feature that he implemented?

Comment: It is up to you (the OP) to decide which answer to mark as the solution. I do not care too much about the SO karma points. Stefan is the author of the `nlinum` package and he offered me a great help as I came up with that `nlinum` patch for highlighting the current line number.